# scalable architecture with node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, architecture, load-balancing, devops

As a part of next assignment, I need to prepare a scalable and full concurrent supporting node architecture. I am confused with kubernetes/containers concept and really need some help. And I cannot use any paid service! Just plain raw DO servers and load balancers.

Basically a basic sketch/idea/explanation/pointers to The architecture which should explain API endpoints, data service connectivity and data flows between database, server and client is needed!

Here is what I have in my mind:

Client <-> NginX -> Nodejs <-> MongoDB

So above is a standard setup for nodejs based REST APIs I believe. Now how to add scalability to this and concurrency?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you a quick overview and after that just ask more questions in the comments of my answer if you need to know more.

You need a docker image of all your services:

1. You will need an nginx image wich contains your frontend code. (https://serversforhackers.com/c/dckr-nginx-image)
2. You will need a docker image with which contains your backend code.
   (https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/)
3. You will need an simple mongo-db base image.
   (https://medium.com/@pablo_ezequiel/creating-a-docker-image-with-mongodb-4c8aa3f828f2)

Now for beginners I would go to Google Cloud Plattform and set up a manged kubernetes cluster. This is done in 1 minute and you will have a fulll functinal kubernetes environment. (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart) - In the first year you will have 300$ for free usage. So this is more then enough to play arround and set up an environment for your assignment.

Now you will need an Ingress API. The Ingress is the only access point to the Services you will later deploy on your cluster. Lets say your Ingress is listening to 14.304.233. When your write 14.304.233/customerBackend, it will redirect this request to the customerBackend Service (You need to define this of course) More information here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress

Now you need to deploy the images you created. In Kubernetes you have the concept of Pods (see here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/).Normally in each Pod there runs only one container.  Each Pod-Group (f.e all Pods which have an Node Container inside) has one so called Service, which is managing the access on the pod. Let say you want to have 3 instances of your NodeJS backend. Each of the 3 Container will run in a individual pod. If you want to send a request to the backend, it  will go trough the Service, which then redirects the requests to one of the pos. When you need to scale, you simply deploy more pods. The Service automaticly balances the load over the deployed pods.

How many pods you want have is deployt is defined in a so called deployment.yaml
(see: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/).

This is very simular to a docker-compose.yaml but with some more attributes you can configure.

Comment: can't we achieve this by load balancing multiple node.js clusters via Nginx? And use queues?

Comment: Ingress and the Services are usually nothing else then a nginx loadbalancer. I definitly would suggest you to use these.

Comment: correct. so to say, I am not very familiar with the concept of containers/kubernetes. Do you think I can achieve the same result using nginx load balancer and couple of node clusters for the same process to avoid spof? Main concern here is concurrency...

Comment: I dont really understand your question. You dont want to use the Kubernetes concepts? And where is the danger of spoofing when using the Kubernetes concepts?

Comment: SPOF - Single point of failure. I don't want to use containers/kubernetes because I don't understand the idea behind it...maybe i shall learn it soon. But for now nginx as a load balancer for node cluster would be a good approach or not in your opinion...sorry new to all this

Comment: Well, a standard Kubernetes Cluster usually consist at least out of 4 nodes (2 worker nodes and 2 master nodes). Kubernetes also makes it very easy for your to define rules and health checks to make your sure everything is running at all time. I dont see any problems regarding SPOF when using Kubernetes. There are many good tutorials out there on how to get started with kubernetes, and especially with the offering of google cloud plattform it is very easy to set up a cluster with all the features you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171347/discussion-between-benerd-and-leonard-capacete).